# Access denied while installing gurobipy / pysetup (windows)

Tags: python-3.x, gurobi

in google+ I have found the same question, but unfortunately no answer yet. I am using gurobi and pycharm and I wanted to use the gurobipy interface now. 
I cannot install gurobipy on my windows computer. 
What have I done?
1. I checked again whether my license is valid. This is the case.
2. I followed the instructions on the gurobi webside how to install gurobipy. Each time I enter pysetup I am receiving the error message access denied. [Zugriff verweigert is German for Access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZMQl.jpg)
I appreciate your time! Have a good one and cheers

Ralph

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup `gurobipy` for your existing `python` installation you have to:

1. run `pysetup.bat` *as Administrator* (right click -> "run as administrator"). `pysetup.bat` can be found in your `Gurobi <installdir>/bin` directory.
2. in the terminal that opens, enter the path to your existing python installation, where you want to install the `gurobipy`.
3. Hit enter.

Done.